# Finding X, Y coordinates on a curved line using Euclidean distance in R

Tags: r, curve, euclidean-distance

I'm trying to extract three points from a curved line based upon Euclidean distance, following a study I read. Starting from the leftmost point of the curve, I want to extract the X, Y values at the startpoint (which I can do already), the midpoint and two-thirds of the way through the line. However, I don't know how to use Euclidean distance to find corresponding X and Y values, and the study who's method I wish to replicate doesn't outline how this was done, so was hoping that you good people might be able to help.

If I have data that looks a little like this (the real data contains 21 X and 21 Y values for each line):

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4), y = c(1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.25, 0.8, 0, -1.2, -2.8, -4))
```

That visually appears something like:

```
plot(df)
lines(df)
```

[image: Example curve]

With Euclidean distance of:

**Updated based on feedback from Roland and Bertil**

```
cumsum(diag(as.matrix(dist(cbind(df$x, df$y), method = "euclidean"))[-1,]))

[1]  1.000000  2.000000  3.030776  4.127362  5.407987  6.970037  8.856833 10.418883
```

How do I extract points midway through the line and 75% of the way through the line?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want `dist(cbind(df$x, df$y), method = "euclidean")` or, since you need only the first column, `with(df, sqrt((x- x[[1]])^2 + (y - y[[1]])^2))`. However, are you sure that the relevant points are not just defined by the x values? Or that the Euclidean distances should be used and not the distance on the curve (then `cumsum(diag(as.matrix(dist(cbind(df$x, df$y), method = "euclidean"))[-1,]))` might be useful)?

Comment: @Roland, thank you for you response. The paper I'm looking at calculated the length of the curve to be the sum of the Euclidean distances between successive pairs of x,y coordinates. They then extracted x,y values at three points along the curve. The extraction of x,y values doesn't seem to have been based on just the x value, unfortunately.

Comment: Oh I see, my bad, this is horribly wrong ^^ I will delete it as it is not useful at all, many thanks for your very respectful comment!

Comment: @Paul This kind of thing is so easy to do. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we calculate the distance between all pints and saves as a matrix

```
dist_m <- dist(df) %>% 
  as.matrix()
```

We can then get the cummulated distance by extracting the lower diagonal `[(2,1), (3,2),...]` and cummaltive sum it up

```
dist_m[2:nrow(dist_m), 1:(nrow(dist_m)-1)] %>% 
 diag() %>% 
 cumsum()
```

the rest should then be quite straight forward

Comment: thank you for your answer. It is useful and aligns with Roland's earlier response.

I just want to follow up on the part that you say should be straight forward (this isn't really my area and I'm quite simple so I'm afraid to say it isn't so straight forward for me). I am thinking that to extract the midpoint x,y coordinates, for example, I should  take the value for half the cummulative total (10.418883/2 = 5.209441). Following this, I should look up the x,y coordinates that are closest to this value -- the 6th set of x,y values in my example. Is this close or am I way off?